# Disabled keyboard state in iOS 6?

Tags: ios5, uiview, ios6, uitextview, first-responder

I have implemented a "token" or "chip" text field similar to the stock messaging apps where a user enters entries which become colored tokens. When a user presses backspace, it highlights the token, and one more backspace deletes it. This all works great on iOS 5.

On iOS 6, however, once my tokens (UIView-based) are highlighted, and they call becomeFirstResponder, the keyboard becomes disabled as seen below. When testing in the simulator using the "hardware keyboard", things still work fine, but a real user on device cannot press backspace again since it is disabled.

How does one avoid this? What calls/properties should I even be looking for? In my research I am unable to find what this mode is called or how it is used.

Thanks!

[image: iOS 5 working properly]
[image: iOS 6 with disabled keyboard]